Underpaid but not willing to be seen as "job hopper". What should I do?
I am underpaid, and I know it
However, I have been working in my current position for less than a year (about six months). My previous job was an internship in a different company that lasted a few months (technically, I was employed, and it was a job like any other). Two short-lived jobs in my resume in a row may tarnish my reputation, I may be seen as a "job hopper". It may cost me in the long run. On the other hand, experience from the two jobs combined amounts to one year, and that's enough to find a job in my country today. It is hard to find a job with no or less than one year of experience, but once you get that first year, you're in the clear
I was hoping bonuses may make up for my low salary. Earlier, we were told the bonus depended on the number of tasks we solved. It doesn't appear to be the case. I got the bonus last Friday, and it was the same as the time before it. I solved a lot more tasks in September than in August, that data is available. One could suggest other factors were considered (how hard the tasks were etc.), but it doesn't seem likely at all as the figure was the same down to a cent (actually, another monetary unit, but you get the point). The most likely explanation is the lead, who shares the overall bonus money among us, forgot to check it beforehand (he's rather careless, frankly)
My company recently published a new job posting for the same position. We, Java devs, were informed they want to add one or two extra devs on the team. The pay they offer in the new posting is about 50% more than what I get
Not fair
I know there are folks on Reddit who get their six figures all right and complain about the same thing. But I am actually underpaid. It's objectively not enough to pay a rent etc.
Beside, architecture is a mess, and the stack is ancient. Some employers pay extra for legacy, not ours. And generally, they have few clues as to how modern software development is done and managed (no MQA, no BA, no SCRUM, no code review, no nothing – heck, devs sometimes even draw icons for the app themselves, that's how bad it is). Mind, it's a mature company with hundreds of employees, not some startup of two people
So I'm considering my options

Quiet option. Quietly start looking for a new job. Quit once it's found

Beggar option. Send a letter to the management and ask for a raise. Suck it up if I don't get my way

Beggar+ option. The same as Beggar option, but it involves quitting if they don't give the raise

Big balls option. Quit to then reapply for the new posting. "I believe I am the prefect match, as my previous job experience is perfectly relevant!" I imagine the look on their faces once I explain my resignation letter! If they rehire me for the new pay, I win. If they don't, I find a better paying job and still win. However, I'm not sure I posses enough confidence at the moment to execute it well. It's certainly what I could do, though. If I were to choose the option that best aligns with my identity as a person, that would definitely be it


So what do you think I should do?

Don't worry that the internship lasted only a few months. Everyone knows that internship only lasts for a few months (and not 1 or 2 years) by nature. So, if you quit this current job, you only spend a short time at 1 real (professional) job, which means you don't really have to worry about being labeled "job hopper". --- Go ahead and look a new job if you want to.

Nobody in the real world counts an internship as a real job except the first company who hire you as a full time employee. Internships are short term by design and definitely not permanent. However, if you have only had your current job you might, rethink the notion you’re underpaid. It’s normal for individuals with practically no experience to be paid less. 6 months isn’t enough experience to look for another job to increase your compensations. Paying newer employees a different rate absolutely is fair. 6 figures for a Java developer with 6 months of experience isn’t realistic.

Short term jobs early in one's career is not a problem as it is common to not fit in with a place and you haven't experienced enough to know how to spot a bad environment during the interview process.

Just do option 1.  Its not a big deal.  "Why did you leave your previous position?"  I was offered a 65% raise, I could not say no.  That will shut up any recruiter.

@PeteB. I chose Beggar+. They don't want to pay (even though I solve ap. 40% of all tasks related to their key product), so I'm going update my resume

Good question, enjoyed reading it, please edit it so it makes the question relevant for anyone rather than just asking for opinions on what to do.  Please see: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Is there an internal protocol to apply for open positions? Some companies have a method to do this that isn't though of a negative.
If you are not happy at your current company, there is no harm looking elsewhere quietly. Don't be concerned about the internship being included as "Job Hopping". One job that "it wasn't a great fit" won't hurt.
If you do move, make it more than just about the money. Ensure that there is a career growth objective to it.
